# Under theme folder, what's sequence of action for index.php, page.php, single.php?

Tags: theme-development, templates

`index.php`, `page.php`, and `single.php`: All three files are under the theme folder and use the Loop to check for posts.

Which one gets executed first, and the next?

What's sequence for WordPress to read those files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the most specific template will be used first if it's available, then WordPress will try the others. It depends on what thing you're looking at (post, page, taxonomy, etc) and where your're looking at it (archive, single).

This is all explained in detail by the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).